# php5-fpm + nginx + Google bot = connection reset by peer

Tags: nginx, php, googlebot

So I just had a nuts hour trying to figure out why my logs went berserk with slow PHP script warnings literally a few times every minute for the last few hours.

I was initially concentrating on the PHP slow logs and PHP error logs freaking out thinking it was my code. It just so happens I was implementing some DNS tweaks which is why I was led down the wrong path.

I eventually checked the nginx error log which revealed line after line of connect reset by peer from pretty much the same IP.

I googled the IPs and found it belongs to Google, so this was clearly a Google bot / spider visiting the site.

Here is a clip of the error log

```
2013/06/06 14:04:05 [error] 12313#0: *7435269 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.187, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:04:05 [error] 12308#0: *7435135 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.167, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:04:05 [error] 12308#0: *7435994 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.199, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:04:12 [error] 12309#0: *7436209 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.168, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:05:12 [error] 12309#0: *7441608 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.177, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:05:15 [error] 12310#0: *7440634 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.219, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q= xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:05:15 [error] 12313#0: *7441634 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.194, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:06:02 [error] 12310#0: *7444721 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.221, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:06:05 [error] 12308#0: *7443911 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.203, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:06:05 [error] 12309#0: *7445423 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.164, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
2013/06/06 14:06:05 [error] 12310#0: *7445640 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 209.85.238.222, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /c.html?q=xyz HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"
```

What is the cause of the connection reset by peer. Would Google bot really be visiting the page and terminating the request, just to check it is alive?

That isn't very nice because it invokes my curl requests which then belong to an orphan thread because the client exited. Meaning they just time out causing slow PHP scripts.

Or have I read this incorrectly?

Comment: Goggle bot will not terminate requests in normal case. They are visiting pages in normal way. Sometimes they hit rate is extremely high, but they do not terminate connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you look a the error message, it says

> while reading response header from upstream

Which means that the issue is not that google is terminating the request, but rather that nginx's upstream, which happens to be php-fpm, is terminating the request. Usually, this is caused by an error the the php code being ran.

Given that we don't have the code, here are some general troubleshooting steps:

- In php-fpm's configuration, increase the values of `request_terminate_timeout`, `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time`.
- Activate error logging in the php.ini or pool .conf configuration files (but not "display_error", if it's a production website).
- Try running a debugger on the running code (xdebug is very useful) to step through the code and you'll stumble upon most issues.